# Null pointer exception in Jmeter report generation in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am running jmeter test in non-gui mode in Jenkins pipeline.

Below are ther versions:

```
Jenkins agent java vaerion : 11
Jmeter version : 5.3
```

The command I run in Jenkins

```
/home/jenkins/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter.sh -f -n -t jmeter_scripts/Suite_master.jmx -l output.jtl -j jmeter.log -p project.properties -e -o results
```

However I see below failure while generating the HTML result file

```
2022-04-29 02:05:29,397 INFO o.a.j.r.p.CsvFileSampleSource: produce(): 1086 samples produced in 66ms on channel 0
2022-04-29 02:05:29,397 INFO o.a.j.r.d.ReportGenerator: Exporting data using exporter:'json' of className:'org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter'
2022-04-29 02:05:29,399 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Found data for consumer statisticsSummary in context
2022-04-29 02:05:29,399 INFO o.a.j.r.d.JsonExporter: Creating statistics for overall
2022-04-29 02:05:29,399 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Error generating the report
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.createStatistic(JsonExporter.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:381) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:262) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.generateReport(JMeter.java:1324) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter$ListenToTest.testEnded(JMeter.java:1261) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:218) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:492) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
[Pipeline] sh
```

BTW I can see jtl file with data as well

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 273418 Apr 29 02:05 output.jtl
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `project.properties` file contain the properties which are absolutely required for the report generation like [`jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/jmeter.properties#L1313) and [`jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/jmeter.properties#L1316)?

If not make sure they're there and contain the desired values.

If you want to pass a set of **project** properties replacing the original *jmeter.properties* file is not the best idea as apart from the aforementioned dashboard-related properties it has several more default values whose absence may lead to unexpected behaviour.

So I would recommend leaving jmeter.properties intact and using `-q` command line argument for passing your custom set of properties to JMeter

```
/home/jenkins/jmeter/apache-jmeter-5.1/bin/jmeter.sh -f -n -t jmeter_scripts/Suite_master.jmx -l output.jtl -j jmeter.log -q project.properties -e -o results
```

More information:

- [Full list of command-line options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I already have theses properties set in `project.properties ` file `jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=500
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_tolerated_threshold=1500
jmeter.reportgenerator.overall_granularity=1000
jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title=Projectn Performance Test Results
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(S[0-9][0-9]_(.*))(-success|-failure)?$ `. The question is where and why does the specific null pointer issue happening?

Comment: The answer is "because something is null"

Comment: I tried running same script with same command in local machine. I was fine and I can see result folder with necessary files to see the HTML file. So I doubt this is something related to Jenkisnpipeline.

Comment: After few testing, noticed that once increased the test run duration, the null pointer was disappared. Ealier `ramp-up/run duration` was `20/120 sec` once increased to `20/300 sec` no error. Still not excatly sure why `run duration` is related to HTML report generation as null pointer error happened in that step.